# How to unmarshal Golang Viper snake_case values

Tags: go, viper-go

How to viper.unmarshal(&c) with Golang and Viper library a snake_case fields:

```
CryptoId string `json:"crypto_id"`
```

Currently I'm getting "" empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this

```
CryptoId string `mapstructure:"crypto_id"`
```

[Reading a slice of maps with Golang Viper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955605/reading-a-slice-of-maps-with-golang-viper)